# Initializing list inline

Tags: c#

I'm getting a weird error when doing this: (.net 2.0)

```
public overrides List<String> getSpaceballs
{
    get { return new List<String>() { "abc","def","egh" }; }
}
```

VS is asking for `;` after `()`. Why?

I sure can do this:

```
public overrides string[] getSpaceballs
{
    get { return new string[] { "abc","def","egh" }; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first option is not legal :)

You can only do that type of initialiser on arrays.

-- Edit: See [Andrew Hare's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34211/andrew-hare) post (and others, below); it is only available in v3 and up.

-- Edit again:

Just to be clear, if your compiler is of 3 or greater, you can target 2.0, to get this to work (because it's compiled down to the code that Andrew shows, below). But if your compiler is 2, then you can't.

Comment: Collection Initializers were added in C# 3.0.

Comment: Could you make the distinction between framework version and compiler version, as he is asking about framework version 2.0.

Comment: Yannick: Uh, what? I don't understand what you mean. I think the indication to review Andrew's post is sufficient; and regardless the OP made it clear he was using 2.0.

Comment: @silky: The OP made it clear he was using .NET 2.0 *in some respect*. He didn't make it clear whether he was *building* with .NET 2.0 or *targeting* .NET 2.0. Both could easily be construed as "using" 2.0.

Answer (score 120):

C#'s [collection initialization syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) is only supported in versions 3 and up (since you mentioned .NET 2.0 I am going to assume you are also using C# 2).   It can be a bit confusing since C# has always supported a similar syntax for array initialization but it is not really the same thing.

Collection initializers are a compiler trick that allows you to create and initialize a collection in one statement like this:

```
var list = new List<String> { "foo", "bar" };
```

However this statement is translated by the compiler to this:

```
List<String> <>g__initLocal0 = new List<String>();
<>g__initLocal0.Add("foo");
<>g__initLocal0.Add("bar");
List<String> list = <>g__initLocal0;
```

As you can see, this feature is a bit of syntax sugar that simplifies a pattern into a single expression.

Answer (score 15):

As the other users point out, that is not supported in 2.0.  However, you can mimic it by doing the following.

```
public overrides List<String> getSpaceballs
{
   get { return new List<String> ( new String[] {"abc","def","egh"} ); }
}
```

Please note that this creates some computational overhead.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case anyone would search for it as well nowadays, there is a neat way to do that using LINQ extensions. Hope it helps someone ;)

```
var list = new string[]{ "1", "2", "3" }.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Where the variable type can be implied (e.g. when passing a parameter), C# 9.0 has an added simplification to @Andrew Hare's answer:

```
list = new() { "foo", "bar" };
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operatorDocs)

> Beginning with C# 9.0, constructor invocation expressions are target-typed. That is, if a target type of an expression is known, you can omit a type name [...]